# Idiomatic way of assigning a value from an if else condition in Rust

Tags: rust

What is the preferred way of creating or assigning one of several objects to variables inside an "if - else" construct in Rust? Because of the scoping, it seems the variable must be created outside the if - else. Neither of the ways I've thought of seem very nice. Using strings as an example, here's one way, but it generates a warning about an unused assignment:

```
let mut s = String::new();
if condition {
    s = "first".to_string();
} else {
    s = "second".to_string();
}
```

Another alternative is this:

```
let mut s = "second".to_string();
if condition {
    s = "first".to_string();
}
```

It's shorter and doesn't generate a warning, but means `s` is being assigned twice, and means that `"second".to_string()` runs but is wasted if `condition` is true. If instead of simple string creation these were expensive operations (perhaps with side effects) this method wouldn't be suitable.

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In Rust, an if/else block is an expression. That is to say, the block itself has a value, equivalent to the last expression in whatever section was executed. With that in mind, I would structure your code like this:

```
let s = if condition {
    "first"
} else {
    "second"
}.to_string();
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I had seen that mentioned before but had not caught on to the significance of it.

Comment: @Bob: The fact that `if` and `match` are expression really trims down the number of cases in which mutable variables are necessary, embrace it wholeheartedly :)

Comment: I have seen the conditions like
if let p = fun() {

} else {}

What is the purpose of making an assignment inside the if condition?

Comment: How would this generalize to assigning two or more variables based on the same conditions? Repeating the if block for each assignment sure can't be the answer.

Comment: @Christoph90: Use a tuple: `let (a, b) = if condition { ("first", 1) } else { ("second", 2) };`

Answer (score 5):

Giving another perspective of Benjanmin's answer might help to deepen someone's understanding of what is happening.

Same thing done by the compiler just written in another way:

```rust
let s = String::from(if condition {
    "first"
} else {
    "second"
});
```