# Rust lifetimes in if statement

Tags: rust

I have an if statement in a for loop, and I want it to create a variable with the lifetime of that iteration of the for loop.

```rust
    for condition_raw in conditions_arr {
        println!("{}", condition_raw);
        let matching = !condition_raw.contains('!');
        if matching {
            let index = condition_raw.find('=').unwrap_or_default();
        } else {
            let index = condition_raw.find('!').unwrap_or_default();
        }
        let key = &condition_raw[..index];
    }
```

`let key = &condition_raw[..index];`  currently throws cannot find value `index` in this scope
not found in this scope rustc E0425

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'll ignore the `condition` variable which does not seem to be used at all in your example.*

A `let` statement creates a binding that holds at most for the current scope. For this reason, when you create the `index` variable *inside* the `if`, you are not making it accessible anywhere else. There are two ways to solve this issue.

The first way is to explicitly declare `index` as being part of the outer scope, and only define it inside the if statement.

```rust
for condition_raw in conditions_arr {
    let matching = !condition_raw.contains('!');
    let index;
    if matching {
        index = condition_raw.find('=').unwrap_or_default();
    } else {
        index = condition_raw.find('!').unwrap_or_default();
    }
    let key = &condition_arr[..index];
}
```

There is no risk of accidentally not defining `index`, since Rust will make sure that `index` is defined (exactly once) in all possible branching of your code before it is used. Yet, it's not a pretty solution because it violates a "locality" principle, that is that pieces of code should have effects on or pieces of code that are *sufficiently close*. In this case, the `let index;` is not too far from its definition, but it could be arbitrarily far, which makes it painful for someone who reads your code to remember that there is a declared but not yet defined.

Alternatively, you could use the fact that most things in Rust are expressions:

```rust
for condition_raw in conditions_arr {
    let matching = !condition_raw.contains('!');
    let index = if matching {
        condition_raw.find('=').unwrap_or_default();
    } else {
        condition_raw.find('!').unwrap_or_default();
    }
    let key = &condition_arr[..index];
}
```

But, in fact, you could factorize your code even more, which is usually better:

```rust
for condition_raw in conditions_arr {
    let matching = !condition_raw.contains('!');
    let index = condition_raw.find(if matching {
        '='
    } else {
        '!'
    }).unwrap_or_default();
    let key = &condition_arr[..index];
```

Or, even more

```rust
for condition_raw in conditions_arr {
    let index = condition_raw
        .find('!')
        .or_else(|| condition_raw.find('='))
        .unwrap_or_default();
    let key = &condition_arr[..index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An idiomatic way to assign variables from an if else statement is as follows:

```rust
let index: usize = if matching {
            condition_raw.find('=').unwrap_or_default()
        } else {
            condition_raw.find('!').unwrap_or_default()
        };
```

[Idiomatic way of assigning a value from an if else condition in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981783/idiomatic-way-of-assigning-a-value-from-an-if-else-condition-in-rust)

> In Rust, an if/else block is an expression. That is to say, the block itself has a value, equivalent to the last expression in whatever section was executed. With that in mind, I would structure your code like this:

Comment: One can even compress it further to `condition_raw.find(if matching { '=' } else { '!' }).unwrap_or_default()`